# getting 404 error while mapping get/customers

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

[image: mapping is also correct]I try to change the get mapping request add support for jackson but i did not get the where i get wrong i did not get any error in tomcat server my database is also connect but while mapping i get the not found error

[image: getting 404 error not found while mapping api/get[![index file is working fine<code>enter code here</code>]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcdYN.png)

pom.xml file

```
`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.restCrud</groupId>
  <artifactId>realCrud</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>realCrud</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.10</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.10</maven.compiler.target>
      <spring.version>5.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
      <springsecurity.version>5.3.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>

      <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
      <servlet-api-version>4.0.1</servlet-api-version>
      <jsp-version>2.1</jsp-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jsp-version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.0.pr3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>`
```

`restController i getting an error 404 not found but i give the properScanning file[image: all the file are in the com.restCrud]

```
package com.restCrud.controller;

import com.restCrud.entity.Customer;
import com.restCrud.services.customerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class restController {

    @Autowired
    customerService customerservice;

    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public List<Customer> getCustomer(){
        return customerservice.getCustomer();
    }

    @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
    public Customer getCustomer( @PathVariable int id){
        return customerservice.getCustomer(id);
    }

//    @GetMapping("/save")
//    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer){
//        customerservice.saveCustomer(customer);
//    }
//
//    @GetMapping("/delete")
//    public void deleteCustomer(int id){
//        customerservice.deleteCustomer(id);
//    }

}
```

`
Dispatcher configuration file

```
 package com.restCrud.configuration;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

@ComponentScan(basePackages ="com.restCrud")
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement

public class dispatcherconfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {



    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource combo=new ComboPooledDataSource();
        combo.setUser("springstudents");
        combo.setPassword("springstudents");
        combo.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker/");
        combo.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") ;

        combo.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        combo.setMinPoolSize(5);
        combo.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        combo.setMaxIdleTime(3000);
        return combo;
    }

    @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean=new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        Properties props=new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.restCrud.entity");
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory session){

        HibernateTransactionManager obj=new HibernateTransactionManager();
        obj.setSessionFactory(session);
        return obj;
    }



}
```

Comment: Im not sure I quite got what the issue is. But are you calling the controller with correct mapping - localhost:8080/api/customers ?

Comment: i did not able to find the error is there is an way to find the error

Comment: i calling it with correct mapping i also share the snapshot

Comment: Do share the code for `servletInit` class as well

Comment: If you get a 404 than you will have the according error message written to stdout in your IDE. Normally something like this will be printed out: "WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/yourappname/nonexistingpage] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'". Check for misspelling. And b.t.w in my application I need to omit the leading slash in the requestmapping so it resolves to @GetMapping("customers")